# Duplicate *.aj files created by roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I have a roo project that I have been working on for a little bit with no real problems.  I had a couple of weird errors so I restarted STS then cleaned the project and restarted the roo shell.

Now, in the package explorer, I have duplicates of all of the *.aj files created by roo.  They really are the same file since when I double click on each, the same file opens (if it is already open in a tab, then it brings it to the front instead of opening another tab).  I do not want to remove roo.  How can I get rid of the duplicates that roo has created?

Comment: Less than 100 rep, so can answer my own question but here is how I fixed it.  Ok so I don't what caused this but here is how I was able to fix it.  Right click the project>Close project.  Right click the project again> Open project.  Refreshed, and all of the duplicates were gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am copying your answer from your comment, so you can accept this and mark this question as answered since it's showing up as an unanswered question when it is not.

> Ok so I don't what caused this but here is how I was able to fix it.
>   Right click the project>Close project. Right click the project again>
>   Open project. Refreshed, and all of the duplicates were gone.

Btw, are you sure you can't answer your own question? I was able to do so and I have less than 100 rep. With my rep I cannot comment on yours, so I needed to add this comment to my answer.

Comment: Worked for me.  I was playing with the 'duplicate .aj file filter' but it wasn't doing anything at all, but all I had to do was open and close my projects as you suggested.